# Formula that combines name and true/false into a third column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need help to make a Formula that combines name and true/false into a third column.

See image for more information.

I want the employees who are "Leader of the day", to have their names listed ind the: Leader of the day (F1): if that if they have chosen "TRUE" in the column in D3:D10

TRUE in the column in D3:D10 = Name/names from A3:A10 in column F1

[image]

Comment: The question doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. Please describe the spreadsheet and add sample input data and the corresponding expected result as text. Show what you have tried and be specific about were you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=join( ", "; filter(A3:A10; D3:D10) )`

Comment: Perhaps also IFERROR() in case no value is selected?

Comment: Perhaps, depending on OP's exact requirements, which are currently unknown.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of many possible ways:

`=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,if(D3:D10,A3:A10,"")))`